# Align* command is not working for my equation

Tags: align

I am using overleaf and I am using already "\usepackage{amsmath}".

But, with "align*" it dose not working and I don't have idea how I can fix it.

Would you please give some advice ?

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
 & ^{e}\mathrm{\hat{P}} = \, ^{e}\mathrm{V} \\ 
 & ^{e}\mathrm{\hat{V}} = ge_{3}-\frac{f}{m}Re_{3}  \\ 
 & \dot{\Theta} =  W \cdot \,^{b}\mathrm{\omega} \\
 & J \cdot \,^{b}\mathrm{\dot{\omega}} \, = -^{b}\mathrm{\omega} \times (J \cdot \, ^{b}\mathrm{\omega})+G_{a}+\tau 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome! What are you doing with all these `\mathrm`s? How should e.g. `\mathrm{\omega}`  be typeset?

Comment: Thanks for your time !
I thought it is necessary when use left superscript. because it was used in page that I have referenced to learn how to use left superscript. ( I just did copy paste ;) ) 
after delete also situation is same..

Comment: \begin{align*}

\begin{cases}

^{e}\mathrm{\hat{P}} & = \, ^{e}\mathrm{V} \\

^{e}\mathrm{\hat{V}} & = ge_{3}-\frac{f}{m}Re_{3} \\

\dot{\Theta} & = W \cdot \,^{b}\mathrm{\omega} \\

J \cdot \,^{b}\mathrm{\dot{\omega}} \, & = -^{b}\mathrm{\omega} \times (J \cdot \, ^{b}\mathrm{\omega})+G_{a}+\tau

\end{cases}

\end{align*}

Comment: I solved it. ampersand should be placed left side of equal symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? `\prescript` for the left superscript and `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
  \prescript{e}{}{\hat{P}} &= \prescript{e}{}{V} \\ 
  \prescript{e}{}{\hat{V}} &= g\,e_{3}-\frac{f}{m}R\,e_{3}  \\ 
  \dot{\Theta} &=  W \cdot\prescript{b}{}{\omega} \\
  J \cdot \prescript{b}{}{\dot{\omega}} &=
  -\prescript{b}{}{\omega} \times (J \cdot 
  \prescript{b}{}{\omega})+G_{a}+\tau 
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`align*` is not needed here, you could use `\[...\]`, but since the question is on `align*`, I kept it.

Comment: I appreciate for your help !

Comment: @유민재 I am always excited to meet other cats. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With use of `\prescript`  defined in `mathtools` package (as suggested in @Schrödinger's cat [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549030/align-command-is-not-working-for-my-equation/549032#549032) ) and `empheq` math environment defined in the `empheq` package which also load `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
  \prescript{e}{}{\widehat{P}}  & = \prescript{e}{}{V}              \\
  \prescript{e}{}{\widehat{V}}  & = g\,e_{3}-\frac{f}{m}R\,e_{3}    \\
            \dot{\Theta}    & = W \cdot\prescript{b}{}{\omega}  \\
  J \cdot \prescript{b}{}{\dot{\omega}} 
                            & = -\prescript{b}{}{\omega} \times (J \cdot
                                \prescript{b}{}{\omega}) + G_{a}+\tau
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate for your help !

Comment: @유민재, you can up-vote the answer (by clicking on the up-pen at left top side of answer) and also accept one of received answer which you the most liked by clicking on the check mark  at left top side of answer).